# Chef :: remote_file unable to download file from FTP

Tags: ruby, ftp, chef-infra

I am developing a recipe to download some file from FTP server. I am successfully able authenticate the FTP server and fetching the list of the files. But when my chef is executed to download the files I am getting error.

Here is code

```
fileList.each do |file|
  remote_file "C:\\" + file do
    source URI::encode("ftp://user:password@server/folder/" + file)
    action :create_if_missing
  end
end
```

and here is  error's log

```
PS C:\chef-repo> chef-apply .\cookbooks\visireview-sqlserver-config\recipes\ftp_restore_db.rb
[2016-02-17T17:14:20+05:00] WARN: ftp://user:password@server/folder/file.bak was an invalid URI. Trying to escape invalid characters
[2016-02-17T17:14:20+05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to C:/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-02-17T17:14:20+05:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::InvalidRemoteFileURI: "ftp://user:password@server/folder/file.bak" is not a valid `source` parameter for remote_file. `source` must be an absolute URI or an array of URIs.
```

Please spare some of your previous time and help me to get rid of this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you replaced too much of the real content. Probably something in the username, password, or hostname is causing a problem with the URI parsing.

```
> URI.parse("ftp://user:password@server/folder/file.bak").absolute?
true
```

Get that working with whatever values you actually have and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not working, here very almost 100 % similar is 

url ftp://user:password@server/folder A/folder B/file_name.ext

Comment: Having spaces seems likely to be related then. Does it work without the extra `URI.encode`? I assume you tried that already and added that in an attempt to fix things?

Comment: Yes, I have already given try to URI.encode. BTW without spaces I have the same issue as well.

Comment: Well then what I said above still stands. Put your actual URL in that snippet and make sure it returns true.